# XUnit tests no longer discovered in .Net Core 2

Tags: .net-core, xunit

After moving project from .Net Core 1.1 to .Net Core 2 I just noticed that my xUnit tests are not discovered in VS 2017 anymore...

any ideas how to get them back? :)

**UPDATE**

After some deeper research I found out that my problem related to this error in my test project: "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.1.0"

more details here: 
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/95070/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-systemruntime-vers.html

Comment: Whatvkind of discovery? Console? VS?

Comment: VS. Edited description

Comment: what kind of project it is containing the test cases? If .NET Framework 4.5.x, upgrade to 4.6.1 and above.

Comment: no, I moved my test project from NetCore 1.1/NetStandard 1.6 to NetCore 2/NetStandard 2. Updated Microsoft related packages to version 2 as well. And after that xUnit tests (that also inside NetCore 2 project now) diapered

Comment: Can you provide csproj?

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the exact same issue and after banging my head for a couple of hours I discovered that xunit in .Net Core 2 requires your Target Framework must be netcoreapp2.0 and not netstandard2.0.

Sample working CS Proj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: I had a similar issue, and it turned out that I had `xunit.runner.console` instead of `xunit.runner.visualstudio` in my csproj. Thanks for your sample, this is what highlighted the issue to me.